# PHP / MySQL site using caching. What makes this work most of the time?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, gzip

Our previous webmaster set up this site and the caching he set up works fine for most browsers but I have found that some versions of Opera don't work and some online SEO tools like [Submit Express Analyzer](http://www.submitexpress.com/analyzer/).  I suspect that it's an issue with headers.  I've read about ob_start("ob_gzhandler") but I'm not sure how I can implement it in this scenario.

The site is all controlled by a router file, unique controller files for each type of page and .htaccess.  In the router file, the code below is set in place to look for a cached version of the page and load the content, otherwise, load the page.

The caching compresses the page content with gzencode and stores it in the database in a cache table with a uri hash.  If the cached file exists, the content is pulled from the database.

Opera displays a blank page and the Submit Express Test does not recognize a page.  I am almost certain that the .htaccess file has nothing to do with the issue.  The code below is where I think the issue resides.

```
<?php
$loadTime = microtime(true);
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['var']))
    $_SESSION['var'] = rand(0, 2);
if (!isset($_SESSION['var2']))
    $_SESSION['var2'] = rand(0, 4);
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/common.php');

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$request = explode('/', substr($uri, 1));
$request = preg_replace('/\..*/', '', $request);
$uriHash = sha1($uri);

if($uri == '/') //This is the Index...
{
```

Irrelevant Index Code

```
}
try
{ // LOOKS FOR CACHE IN DB BASED ON URI
$cache = $GLOBALS['db']->getRow("SELECT * FROM cache_tbl WHERE uri_hash = '$uriHash'");
}catch ( Exception $e ) {
$cache = array();
}

if ( !empty($cache) && ($cache['mod_date'] * 60 * 60 * 24) > $loadTime ) 
{ // IF NO CACHE IN DB, SETS HEADERS FOR COMPRESS OR NO COMPRESS
    $HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"];
    if( headers_sent() )
        $encoding = false;
    else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, 'x-gzip') !== false )
        $encoding = 'x-gzip';
    else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING,'gzip') !== false )
        $encoding = 'gzip';
    else
        $encoding = false;
    $compressed = $cache['contents'];
    if ( $encoding ) {
        header("Content-Encoding: ".$encoding);
        echo $compressed;
    }
} else {
if ($request[0] == 'venues') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('Location: '.HOST.$request[1].'.html');
}
```

More Code

```
if ( // Irrelevant Conditions ) {
    $contents = ob_get_clean();
    echo $contents;

    $compressed = gzencode($contents, 7);

    try {
        Admin::add('cache_tbl', array('uri_hash' => $uriHash, 'contents' => $compressed, 'mod_date' => $loadTime));
    } catch(Exception $e) { ; }

    ob_end_flush(); 
}
}
```

There's a lot going on in this file and I tried to cut out as much stuff as possible to eliminate confusion.  Any help is obviously greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you consider providing a link that displays okay in other browsers but fails in Opera?

Comment: Sorry, I can't... confidentiality reasons.

Comment: Welp, it's most likely an HTTP error. Some HTTP clients (browsers) are more forgiving than others.

Comment: I just saw that most of this code was based off an example on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php#88044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this one looks nasty.

Firstly, the error handling is awful - swallowing errors like that in a code section that gets called on every page sucks.

Secondly, most web servers will handle GZIP etc. pretty much out of the box - there's really no reason to invent this yourself.

Thirdly, it may be because of the way you've split up the code, but I think that in the "IF" block below, there's no case for echoing out the content if the current browser does not accept compressed content.

```
if ( !empty($cache) && ($cache['mod_date'] * 60 * 60 * 24) > $loadTime ) 
{ // IF NO CACHE IN DB, SETS HEADERS FOR COMPRESS OR NO COMPRESS
    $HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"];
    if( headers_sent() )
        $encoding = false;
    else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, 'x-gzip') !== false )
        $encoding = 'x-gzip';
    else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING,'gzip') !== false )
        $encoding = 'gzip';
    else
        $encoding = false;
    $compressed = $cache['contents'];
    if ( $encoding ) {
        header("Content-Encoding: ".$encoding);
        echo $compressed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of factors but most of the time if extra debris in the compressed version that's being sent to the browsers and some can't unroll the page with that stuff in them.

Usually there are just some extra lines at the top, E_NOTICES (use `error_repoting(0);` to suppress) and maybe even the encoding used inside the storage tables. Outside of that, it might just be the outdated compressing extension for PHP, and Opera uses that method.

I'm not sure if `file_get_contents('...')` retrieves the gzipped version but if it doesn't, open the site in Opera and use something like WireShark to see exactly what the browser receives.